# Mysql empty query

Tags: php, mysql

So I have 4 columns in my table. The first two are display name and username. The reason why I dont `echo` the username is that it is a md5 string, to be more secure. So i'm trying to fetch the display name associated with the username that is logged in (`the $_COOKIE["USERNAME"]`), but the `$displayuser` returns an empty query. Also I'm not sure about `WHERE username = {$c_user}`, the part with `{$c_user}`. Any solutions?

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['USERNAME']))
{
$c_user = $_COOKIE["USERNAME"];
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","accounts");
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT 'display name' FROM 'account_info' WHERE username = {$c_user}");
$displayuser = mysqli_query($con,$result);
echo $displayuser;
}
```

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: change `display name` to `display_name`

Comment: An inverted comma is not the same thing as a backtick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'display name' can't be the right column name since there can't be spaces in columns.

and Quentin is right. applied to your example you need to do it like this:

```
//see if there is any result
if($result = mysqli_query($con, result))
{
    while($fields = mysqli_fetch_field($result))
    {
        echo $fields->display_name;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The return value of `mysqli_query` is not a string. It is a `mysqli_result` object or (if the query failed) `FALSE`.

You need to test to see if it is `FALSE` or not (and [examine the error](http://php.net/mysqli_error) if it is (I'm pretty sure that using single quotes around column names will throw an error, if you quote them they should be quoted with backticks)), then you can test to see [if you have any results](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) before looping over them and [getting each row of data](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php).